# Hiding a UINavigationController on start page

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I have a navigationController that starts with a view controller in which in viewDidLoad has:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

I click a button on that page and it transitions to a second view controller in which I put:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

This works fine until I click the Back button in the navigation bar.  How do I keep the navigation bar permanently off the start page but not the transitioned one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` in the viewWillAppear of the firstViewController.

You are adding hidden action in the viewDidLoad method which is called once as the viewControllers in navigation stack are not unloaded when your push to the nextViewController.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}
```

Add this code in your .m file whwre you hide the navigation controller.