# Navigation bar gets hide on pop view controller in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am developing navigation base app in iPhone, I hide navigation bar for whole project in app delegate and show on specific view controller where i need. So I unhide navigation bar in xyz view controller when I pop from this xyz controller navigation bar gets hide on animation of popping view controller. Below I have attached screen shots of this strange behavior.

After Pushing View controller actual Image.
[image]

On Popping View Controller.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this one.. put this line before calling poptoviewcontroller. [self.navigationCtronller.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

Comment: probably you are hiding it in viewDidLoad,try in viewDidAppear

Comment: may be he meant setHidden:NO ?

Comment: Actually you use a single navigation controller for all view controllers. So when you hide/show a navigation bar in single view controller, it will hide/show it in all controllers. So you need to show a navigation bar where you need and hide it again when the viewWillDisappear method of the view controller as @@karthika answer.

Comment: Please make sure you are not doing this same mistake as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798075/hiding-a-uinavigationcontroller-on-start-page/18798110#18798110)

Answer (score 4):

In XYZ viewController,

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you unhide navigation bar any of controller then it will display in all application if you does not hide it. So if you want to show in only screen then in viewWillApper,make it unhide and in viewWillDisapper make it hide.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry It didn't help, I set navigation bar true for whole project but it did not work. Any suggestion where I am doing wrong .

Comment: What are you doing in xyx controller's viewwilldisapper method ?